# Place order button to automatically download

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, checkout

I'm new here and was directed to try this forum for my quandary with WooCommerce.
I’ve created downloadable products that are free. – I’m using Storefront WooCommerce Theme for WordPress.
– Before the download is available I would like the users information ie: email, name. I’m using the checkout page (place order) for this and bypassing the cart. So instead of collecting payment I’m collecting contact info. I have customized that page and buttons to only gather the information required for download.
– Once they enter the information they are able to download the file, but only from a different page (another click). I’d like download to automatically download on the place order button click.(I've changed the text to read: download specifications)

In summary:
– I would like to have the file download automatically without the place order summary page more of a thank you for your interest page.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you again for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the negative votes, I thought this was a place to share and find answers.
I did a work-around which works for now. I may revisit this later. There are still 3 clicks but the flow is a lot nicer.
• I copied the woo thank you php check out template to my child theme and made some custom changes to eliminate the extra order information
• changed button title for smoother flow while still gather the user information in my order information.
• I can trim the template even more but that will take a while because the download function is attached to the order table which is actually the information I want to record.
• Then, I thought about attaching a form to the button at the single product page to capture the user info but that opens another can of worms in record keeping since it won’t populate the order table.
What I wanted to do requires lots of heavy lifting which will take some time for me to figure. If I come up with the answer to my original question I will share with the forum.